# How to read data from file to int/float values in c++?

Tags: c++, char, int, ifstream

it might be that this question has already been asked, I already found similar topics but I could still not solve my problem.
I have a data file generated by IDL that contains integers and float values. I would like to read in this data file in C++.
What I did until now:

```
fstream prjfile;
prjfile.open("fileName", ios::in|ios::ate);
if (prjfile.is_open() == false) {
    std::cout << "Cannot open project file\n";
}
else {
    std::vector <char> memPrj(0);
    std::cout << "project size" << prjfile.tellg() << std::endl;
    int sizePrj;
    sizePrj = prjfile.tellg();
    //store all values of the file in memPrj vector
    memPrj.resize(sizePrj);
    prjfile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    prjfile.read(&memPrj[0], sizePrj);
    //now change the integer values to int
    vector<int> mask;
    //store the values in the mask vector
    mask.push_back(memPrj[0] - '0' + 48);
    mask.push_back(memPrj[1] - '0' + 48);
    mask.push_back(memPrj[2] - '0' + 48);
}
```

Like this I get the values

```
memblockPrj[0] - '0' + 48 = -112
memblockPrj[1] - '0' + 48 = 0
and memblockPrj[2] - '0' + 48 = -112
```

While the values should be: 144,257, 144

Does anyone has an idea where my mistake is? 
The rest of the elements of the data are float values. How can I convert char values to float?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you are correct, there are already a plethora of similar questions.  Search the internet for "StackOverflow c++ read file comma separated".

Comment: IDL=? in this context

Comment: _" I already found similar topics but I could still not solve my problem"_ Yeah thing is, without knowing what exactly you found confusing about them, we can't reliably help you without merely repeating the existing 20,000 answers while not progressing you any further towards understanding. Then it's 20,001 for the next guy. Please be more clear about what you didn't grok in existing guidance.

Comment: Why are you subtracting `'0'` and adding 48?  I believe 48 is the ASCII value for `'0'`.

Answer (score 0):

Repeat >> reads in loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::fstream myfile("D:\\data.txt", std::ios_base::in);

    float a;
    while (myfile >> a)
    {
        printf("%f ", a);
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
45.779999 67.900002 87.000000 34.889999 346.000000 0.980000
```

If you know exactly, how many elements there are in a file, you can chain >> operator:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::fstream myfile("D:\\data.txt", std::ios_base::in);

    float a, b, c, d, e, f;

    myfile >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e >> f;

    printf("%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n", a, b, c, d, e, f);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `printf()` for output in c++?

Comment: Why are you using `printf` (C stream) and C++ stream (`fstream`)?  You should stick with one stream style.

Comment: Your example doesn't expand very well.  If I know there are 1000 elements in a file, I'm not going to use one line to read in all 1000.  Consider a loop and `std::vector`.

Comment: Also, the OP's data file has commas.  Your solution doesn't handle the commas.

Answer (score 0):

You are making life too complicated.
Here's the essence:

```
std::string text_line;
while (std::getline(prjFile, text_line))
{
  int value;
  std::istringstream text_line;
  text_line >> value;
  mask.push_back(value);
  std::string comma;
  std::getline(text_line, comma, ',');
  text_line >> value;
  mask.push_back(value);
  std::getline(text_line, comma, ',');
  text_line >> value;
  mask.push_back(value);
}
```

Since reading an integer will only read up to a decimal point when encountering a floating point number, the remaining characters are skipped until the next comma.

**Edit1:**
An alternative is to read the values as floating point, the convert them to integer before appending to the vector.